# Google Calendar Api : How to send notification email to attendee when i add it to an event?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-api, google-calendar-api

I am updating availables shifts in a google calendar to book meetings.
I would like to send a email invitiation when I add a new attendee.

I have tried `event.sendNotifications` but it is now deprecated.

So I move on `event.sendUpdates = 'all'` but it is raising an error :

`NoMethodError in PagesController#book undefined method sendUpdates=' for #<Google::Apis::CalendarV3::Event:0x00007ff2a9b12ff8>`

Here is my code :

```rb
service = init_google_api
event_id = params[:id]
event = service.get_event(ENV['CALENDAR_ID'], event_id)
event.summary = "confirmed"
event.sendUpdates = 'all'
event.attendees = [
  {
    email:'test-email@gmail.com',
    responseStatus: 'accepted'
  }
]
result = service.update_event(ENV['CALENDAR_ID'], event.id, event)

event = service.get_event(ENV['CALENDAR_ID'], event_id)
result = service.update_event(ENV['CALENDAR_ID'], event.id, event)
```

When I remove the line `event.sendUpdates = 'all'`, everything is working well.

If someone knows how to fix it or where is my error. Thanks !

Comment: where have  you seen that event notifications is deprecated?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At calendar API, `sendUpdates` is used as the query parameter. So how about this modification?

#### From:

```
result = service.update_event(ENV['CALENDAR_ID'], event.id, event)
```

#### To:

```
result = service.update_event(ENV['CALENDAR_ID'], event.id, event, send_updates: 'all')
```

#### Reference:

- [update_event()](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/google/google-api-ruby-client/Google/Apis/CalendarV3/CalendarService#update_event-instance_method)
- [Events: update](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events/update)

If this was not the result you want, I apologize.

Comment: For insert: client.insert_event(calendar_id, event, send_updates: 'all')